# jquery deleting some text from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a some table data that looks like this:

```html
<td class="homebranch">
  This is some Text!
  <span class="location">Texas</span>
</td>
```

How can I use jQuery to remove the text (This is some Text) but keep the span class?

Comment: Quick solution would be to select the span and set it as the `html()` of the parent.

Comment: select the span and set its content to empty string?
 jQuery(".location").html("");

Comment: @Matt.C The OP doesn't want to alter the `span`. They want to alter the text prior to it.

Comment: apoligies, misread!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the text node that is the first child of the `td` and set the `nodeValue` to `""`. In order to do this, you must extract the `td` from the JQuery wrapped set by passing `[0]` to the set. This returns a regular DOM node, that you can then call `firstChild` on to get to the text node.

```js
$("td.homebranch")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="homebranch">
    This is some Text!
    <span class="location">Texas</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: How to remove, if it not the first element

Comment: @whoami Then, we need another solution (different DOM navigation instruction - loop over the child nodes and look for text nodes). But, based on the question, this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the html to the elements that should remain.

```js
$(".homebranch").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(".location", this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="homebranch">
      This is some Text!
      <span class="location">Texas</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="homebranch">
      This is some Text!
      <span class="location">Another Texas</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```